# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsbyTagName' of null at test.js:1, in Microsoft Edge (latest version)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, microsoft-edge

This is the html page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>  
<head> 
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title> 
        Testing HTML File
    </title> 

    <script src="test.js"></script>

</head> 
<body> 
    <p>book</p>
    <a href = "https://google.co.in">Follow Google Here</a>
</body> 
  
</html>
```

This is the 'test.js' script:

```
let link = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
console.log(link.href);
```

I am using Microsoft Edge to run the JavaScript code and trying to find the first occurrence of the anchor tag. How to solve this error?

Comment: You've got your answer(s) below, [but your code is really not good in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474). Why scan the entire document for all the `a` elements, and then create a node list to contain references to them all and then throw that all away just to get a single reference to just the first `a` in that node list? That's a big waste of resources. Instead, just scan for the first `a` and be done: `document.querySelector("a");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is loaded before the DOM is completely loaded, therefore the element does not exist yet when you try to access it.

Either include your javascript file at the end of your page or put your code in

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { // your code; }
```

so it will fire only when the DOM is loaded.

Comment: What @Ash said in his answer, is it the same thing what you explained as "Either include your javascript file .....", or is loading DOM before loading the entire html page, fire scripts faster? Or is it the same thing, loading DOM and loading entire html page?

Comment: It's pretty much the same, if you prefer having your script in the head tag, use defer. It will execute when the DOM is ready, just before the DOMContentLoaded event is fired. Performance wise, it should be the same :)

Comment: @PrateekParashar Placing the script just before the closing `body` is the best approach because it doesn't rely on setting up an additional event handler, so there's less code to write and one less handler to store in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Just add 'defer' to your script import.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp